# how to use url parameter for attachment on FB.api javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I am new to the FB api. I want to upload a photo that user uploads as a form attachment.

From [FB Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos#Creating) : It shows that "url" parameter takes a url of already uploaded photo or a file attachment as a value.

My code:

```js
 FB.api(
   "/me/photos",
   "POST",
   {
     "message": $('#description').val(),
     "url": $('#attachment')
   },
   function (response) {
     if (response && !response.error) {
       /* handle the result */
       console.log("posting");
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
     }
   }
 );
```

And

```html
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" data-buttonBefore="true"/>
```

But it shows following error.
*"Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('file') does not support selection."*

Does anyone have solution to this problem or any alternatives?

Comment: You have an HTML Element as URL. Is it possible that you need $('').text() or .val() of it?

Comment: No, One can't use .val() because it gives something like this "C:/fakepath/image.name" due to security reason.